# Imprimir de console a document javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema a la hora de mandar a imprimir, ya que con la función `console.log()` si sale el resultado pero me piden que este resultado se ponga en un input text con un `document.getElementById()`

```
var frase = document.getElementById('cadena').value;
var letterCount = frase.split(/\W/).join('').length;
var contadorLetras = letterCount.toString();
console.log(letterCount);
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML= contadorLetras;
```

Comment: ¿cuál es la variable que quieres imprimir en el input?

Comment: pues se supone que es para contar en un cadena cuantos números hay

Comment: Eso lo comprendo lo que no me queda claro es cual de todas esas variables es la que deseas mostrar en el input

Comment: ohh ok, es letterCount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El uso de innerHTML sirve para modificar el valor de etiquetas tales como:

- p
- div
- span
- a

etc.

Como puedes ver en este ejemplo:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="parrafo">Hola: </p>
    <script>
        let caja = document.getElementById("parrafo")
        caja.innerHTML = "a todos"
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Sin embargo para elementos del DOM tales como los `inputs` se debe utilizar uno de sus atributos que es `value` de esta forma:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="caja">
    <script>
        let caja = document.getElementById("caja")
        caja.value = "Hola"
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Dado lo anterior, entonces es neceasario que tu código se vea de este modo:

```
var frase = document.getElementById('cadena').value;
var letterCount = frase.split(/\W/).join('').length;
var contadorLetras = letterCount.toString();
console.log(letterCount);
document.getElementById('resultado').value= letterCount;
```

Comment: gracias, una duda de una cadena necesito saber cuantos caracteres hay sin contar espacios y mandarlo a imprimir, así como aparte otra función que en esa misma cadena me cuente si hay números y cuantos

Comment: esa me parece otra pregunta @Ricardo la cual eres bienvenido a publicar en la comunidad del mismo modo que hiciste con esta, seguro alguien te apoya, yo estoy por desconectarme saludos

Comment: ok si gracias, si ya la tengo lista para publicar solo que tengo que esperar 40 min